# Snowflake CROSS JOIN referencing prior table in VALUES clause

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Does Snowflake CROSS JOIN support referencing other tables in join? This statement produces the error:

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [T.ID1] in VALUES clause

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 2)
    ,   (3, 4)
    ) x(id1, id2)
)
SELECT
    t.*
,   x.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (VALUES
    (t.id1)
,   (t.id2)
) x(id3)
```

This works as expected in MSSQL (using CROSS APPLY instead of CROSS JOIN).

However, hardcoding the values in the cross join works, but is not practical for my use case:

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 2)
    ,   (3, 4)
    ) x(id1, id2)
)
SELECT
    t.*
,   x.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (VALUES
    (1)
,   (2)
,   (3)
,   (4)
) x(id3)
```

It produces the expected result:

```
ID1,ID2,ID3
1,2,1
3,4,1
1,2,2
3,4,2
1,2,3
3,4,3
1,2,4
3,4,4
```

Is there another way to produce the desired result in Snowflake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Snowflake CROSS JOIN support referencing other tables in join?

Yes, it is possible. The ISO SQL Standard  counterpart of CROSS APPLY/OUTR APPLY is called LATERAL JOIN.

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 2)
    ,   (3, 4)
    ) x(id1, id2)
)
SELECT    t.*,   x.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT t.id1) x(id3) -- referencing t.id1
UNION ALL 
SELECT    t.*,   x.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT t.id2) x(id3);
```

[image]

---

Interestingly enough using `SELECT` instead of `VALUES` in that context causes error:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 2)
    ,   (3, 4)
    ) x(id1, id2)
)
SELECT    t.*,   x.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES (t.id1), (t.id2)) x(id3)  
-- regardless of single or more values
```

> SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error

*[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d73bf3a51a01c90d63f2835fd23048a8)*

`UNION ALL` to simulate multiple rows:

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 2)
    ,   (3, 4)
    ) x(id1, id2)
)
SELECT    t.*,   x.*
FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT t.id1 UNION ALL SELECT t.id2) x(id3);
```

> SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Answer (score 2):

There is no CROSS APPLY in Snowflake.

Is this dynamic enough?

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (1, 2)
    ,   (3, 4)
    ) t (id1, id2)
)
SELECT
    t.*,
    third_col
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT ID1 as third_col FROM t UNION ALL SELECT ID2 FROM t)
```

Comment: I liked your answer, however, I chose the other one b/c (although not explicitly stated) it mimics the behavior of MSSQL. Thanks.